# Filter Date Logstash

Tags: date, csv, filter, logstash

I just started with Logstash parsing a CSV document. CSV document only has two columns "Date" and "High". I have read various configurations to parse a date but I can not, giving me error in that field. The date has the format DD / MM / YYYY and error tells me the following:

```
Failed parsing date from field {:field=>"Date", :value=>"Date", :exception=>"Invalid format: \"Date\"", :config_parsers=>"dd/MM/YYYY", :config_locale=>"default=es_ES", :level=>:warn}
```

This is my configuration file to filter Logstash:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/path/to/data.csv"
    start_position => "beginning"    
  }
}

filter {
  csv {
      separator => ","
      columns => ["Date","High"]
  }

  date{
     match => [ "Date", "dd/MM/YYYY" ]
  }

  mutate {convert => ["High", "float"]}

}

output {  
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    action => "index"
    index => "machine"
    workers => 1
    }
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Do you see the two fields being created in your stdout{} output?

Comment: Thank you for answering Alain. On the console I visualize data filtering, showing me at the beginning a warning not to filter the Date field, makes the entire process. Later when I link with Kibana Elasticsearch and can only see the time set out in "timestamp" and not the "Date". The field in the column "High" is well represented.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

In your `date` plugin try to change the letter cases in the `match` setting. Something like this:

```
  date{
      match => [ "Date", "DD/MM/YYYY" ]
  }
```

If not helping try to make them all lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

The format string `dd/MM/yyyy` should work. You can find detailed specifications for formatting strings in [the JodaTime documentation](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/key_format.html).